# Elasticsearch Create Index-- all clusters become unassigned

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to migrate data from ES 1.x to 2.x

For some specific reason I had to go with 2.0

All the snapshots are created correctly, but when I try to restore back into the upgraded ES, the response shows "acknowledged" but all shards become unassigned.

Tried deleting and then creating a new index with nothing in it, using default setting.

the log only shows

```
[2017-06-19 10:22:10,315][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Mountjoy] [test] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
```

and the response is again `{"acknowledged":true}`

But by checking the health, it shows `1497893476 10:31:16 elasticsearch red 1 1 0 0 0 0 10 0 - 0.0%` and no shard was assigned to the index

I checked some other posts and some mentioned the disk issue. I have over 300GB of space on this machine. Is there some setting I need to change to "assign" space to ES?

From this, can we figure out why the shards are not assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.... figured out what went wrong.....

I need to enable the shard allocation......

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d
'{ "transient":
  { "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "all" 
  }
}'
```

This is a direct copy from code listed here: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/elasticsearch-unassigned-shards/#reason-3-you-need-to-reenable-shard-allocation